# Limiting effect of perl script

Tags: perl

I want to run a perl script on a tex-document but not on the preamble.
How can I limit the effect of it to the part of the file below a certain pattern (e.g. `^\\begin\{document\}$`)? This is the script:

```
# Insert the macro \gr{} around Greek passages.

#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Encode;

my $L = qr/[^A-Za-z]/;
my $g = qr/\p{Greek}/;

local $/;           # slurp
$_ = decode('utf-8', <>);

# Remove already existing instances.
s/\\gr
(               # 1
 {
  (             # 2
   (?: \\.          # 3. escaped chars
     | [^{}]
     | (?1)         # recur to 1
   )*
  )  
 }
)
/$2/xg;

# Insert new.
s/(
  [([]*             # begin with puncuation?
  $g                # Greek;
  ($L|\\\w+)*       # contain any non-Latin char or cmd;
  $g                # end with Greek
  [)\]]*            # and puncuation?
  )
/\\gr{$&}/xg;

print encode('utf-8', $_);
```

Comment: You can try read the file into a string and then discard the beginning of the file using a regex substitution

Comment: As @DaveCross said, it's uneasy to help without a code example; however, when dealing with structured documents, Regexp::Grammars could help you (the examples are precisely based on latex). Just a thought.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`local $/` can be used for things other than a complete slurp.  `$/` is the input record separator, and perl reads everything up to and including the input record separator, then returns it as a *line*.  The default value for `$/` is a newline `"\n"`.

If you set the input record separator to undef, then (somehow) perl will never find an input record separator in the file, so you get the whole file returned as a *line*.  But you can set the input record separator to anything you want...

```
$ cat data.txt
I don't want to proccess 
this part of the file.
\begin{document}
I just want to process
the stuff down here.
\begin{document}
hello
```

---

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fname = 'data.txt';
open my $INFILE, '<', $fname;

my ($unprocessed, $needs_processing);

{
    local $/ = "\\begin{document}\n";
    $unprocessed = <$INFILE>;
    $/ = undef;  #Read rest of file no matter what it contains.
    $needs_processing = <$INFILE>;
}

close $INFILE;

print $unprocessed;
say '-' x 10;
print $needs_processing;

--output:--
I don't want to proccess 
this part of the file.
\begin{document}
----------
I just want to process
the stuff down here.
\begin{document}
hello
```

If you want to do inplace editing of the file:

```
use strict;
use warnings; 
use 5.020;
use autodie;
use Data::Dumper;

my $fname = 'data.txt';
my $divider = "\\begin{document}\n";
my $backup = '.bak';

open my $INFILE, '<', $fname;

{
    local ($^I, $/, @ARGV) = ($backup, $divider, $fname);

    CHUNK:
    while(<>) {

        if($. == 1) {    # $. is the line number (starts at 1)
            print;       #STDOUT has been redirected to the file 'data.txt'.
            $/ = undef;  #Read rest of file no matter what it contains.
            next CHUNK;
        }

        #Process $_ here:
        s/e/E/g;

        print;  #STDOUT has been redirected to the file 'data.txt'.
    }

}

close $INFILE;
```

---

```
$ cat data.txt
I don't want to proccess 
this part of the file.
\begin{document}
I just want to procEss
thE stuff down hErE.
\bEgin{documEnt}
hEllo
```

The original file will be in `data.txt.bak`.  If you don't want a backup, assign a blank string to `$^I`.

Note that in your code, the statement:

```
local $/;
```

doesn't do anything useful.  In your code, that statement is not inside a block(= a portion of code surrounded by braces).  `local $/` says:

1. Stash the original value of `$/` somewhere.
2. Assign undef to `$/`.
3. When the block containing `local $/` is exited, assign the original value to `$/`.

But because `local $/;` is not inside a block in your code, no block will be exited, and the original value of `$/` will never be restored.  As a result, there is no point in stashing the original value of `$/`.